# How to monitor how many days from due date?

Tags: community, formula-field

I have a field which is Due Date, and one checkbox Within 10 days.It is a formula field to set to true if the Due Date-Today()==10.But is this field going to be change overtime for example maybe today is not yet in 10 days but in future it will?

If no, how to make it dynamic enough to check the due date everytime?So everytime we query the record , we might see the different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying the record or using the checkbox via UI only then the formula field will evaluate to a result for you at time of query or page load.

If you want to fire workflows and the due date field will not change consider use of time based workflow actions.

If due date changes regularly and needs to fire other tasks then consider a daily apex job to maintain the checkbox field for you rather than a formula.

Added via mobile apologies for brevity.

Comment: mean if i retrieve from the Salesforce report , by right the field will be latest value?if i query thru workbench it wont display the latest value?

Comment: If you use a formula it will read current value in both of those use cases.

Comment: In that case, I will use formua.Initially I was thought that formula only update upon the update of reference field, but as you said it will evaluate during the query.It seem a better option rather than creating apex job just to monitor whether today is the duedate.